# Cotangent bundle tensor product tangent bundle

Tags: geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensor-products

What is the meaning of Cotangent bundle tensor product tangent bundle:

$T^*M\otimes TM$? what will an element of this space be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is isomorphic to $Hom(TM,TM)$. Namely it is the endomorphism bundle of the tangent bundle. In general given two vector spaces(or bundles) we have an isomorphism between $W \otimes V^*$ and $Hom(V,W)$.

Comment: You need $V$ to be finite-dimensional here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Or for $W$ to be finite, no? Either way every element of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ has finite rank.